# Center encoded Polyline - Google MAP API V3

Tags: api, google-maps, center, polyline

I would like to center and autozoom a Map with a dynamic encoded Polyline with API V3.

My encoded Polyine is in trace 1, get from a ASP.net C# server side :

```js
    var trace1 = "<%= scriptString %>";

    vol = new google.maps.Polyline({
        map: map,
        strokeColor: '#ff0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 3
    });



    var trace = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(trace1);

    vol.setPath(trace);

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    bounds.getCenter();
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

But it doesn't works... it center the map over the North Pacific ocean, and my Polyline is in France...

I don't have any Javascript error. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to extend the bounds to include the points on your path.

```js
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
vol.getPath().forEach(function(LatLng) {
   bounds.extend(LatLng);
});
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: Great answer. I just changed `map.setBounds(bounds)` to `map.fitBounds(bounds)`